# Crawl space mono post kicker?

Tags: crawlspace

My rough framing inspection failed because i didn’t have kickers on the mono post. They are welded to the ibeam so I’m not sure the reason why id need it. Can anyone explain how to accomplish this?

I have ijoist for the flooring.

*** edit ***

This what I need

[image]

Comment: Update. I believe this setting kickers for torsion on the beam in places it doesn’t have contact to structural members. Sound right?

Comment: Pictures? This may be in English but you're not speaking my language ;) But yeah, "Steel *Moment* Frame Beam Bracing" sounds like that's it.

Comment: Oh, *wood* ijoists, not ibeams. "They are welded to the ibeam" - what is welded, if the 'kickers' are absent and the joists are made out of wood? Man, I haven't done ijoists in 20y. I don't even remember how to 'block' them with wood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so a *kicker* is the 'blocking' for metal work? It's so the beam can't wrack; be *kicked* over. Ask if it has to go to the mono post (the wut?), or if only to each other, and if it needs more than one row down the center. Or if it looks like the second picture, then how far apart, what size angle iron, and which bolts to use.

"Braced with kicker and wood joist_beams"

https://seblog.strongtie.com/2013/07/steel-moment-frame-beam-bracing/braced-with-kicker-and-wood-joist_beams/

[image]

---

"Steel Moment Frame Beam Bracing"

https://seblog.strongtie.com/2013/07/steel-moment-frame-beam-bracing/

[image]

---

Apparently it requires a truck ton of angle iron, wielding, and bolts.

Comment: This is basically right. Just need to brace torsion on the ibeam where it’s not supported from structural framing